# Books about sql security

Tags: sql, security

Can anybody advice me some goods books for sql protection from hackers? Where it will clearly explain how hackers work and how to secure SQL.

Comment: You should also consider the [database administration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator) and the particular [database management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system) besides SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL server security [this](https://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/gr/sqlsecurity.htm) would be good.

the main security issue with SQL is [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Also look at these resources -

[Google Code University - Web Security.](https://edu.google.com/why-google/privacy-security/) - The second video is specific to cross-site scripting and SQL injection attacks

[Foundations Security Every Programmer Experts Should Know](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590597842)

[W3 School on web security](https://www.w3schools.com/site/site_security.asp)

Comment: The last record of the SQL Server Security article on archive.org is [year 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916142023/http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/gr/sqlsecurity.htm). After that, it redirects to a Lifewire SQL Server Agent article.

Answer (score 1):

You can find useful stuff here:
[Database Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764578014)

[SQL Injection Attack and Defense](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597494240)

[SQL Server Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072225157)

[Implementing Database Security and Auditing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1555583342)

[The Rational Guide To SQL Server 2005 Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932577408)

[SQL Server Security Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592190)

[Writing Secure Code](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FWriting-Secure-Code-Strategies-Applications%2Fdp%2F0735617228&ei=mY1FTcjCOomY8QOXrYGvCQ&usg=AFQjCNFIOJUK65yN5DabkEmcshGKHF3-3g)

And of course the [SQL databases benchmarks here](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform), MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, DB2 and even Sybase.

Comment: Which of the six books do you recommend then?

Comment: Depends on your stand as a database server administrator, database programmer (stored procedure for example) or a web developer interfacing with a database.
If you are a programmer, then definitely and with no more delay, read Writing Secure Code. 
If you are a database admin, start with the benchmarks as well as the Database Hacker's Handbook.